# Separate urls/links in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page from where I get links like this:

`var urls = "http://domain.com/example?p=123https://domain2.com/example?p=123..."`

> What I want is to separate them in Javascript/jQuery and like get an array, I tried with .slice() and more but didn't find any solution...

```
Example:  urls[0] --------  // Should echo "http://domain.com/example?p=123"
          urls[1] --------  // Should echo "https://domain2.com/example?p=123..."
```

Unfortunately I don't have access to the server... Thank you :)

Comment: `urls.replace(/(https+:)/, '%%%$1').split('%%%');` should give you an array of urls.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> var urls = "http://domain.com/example?p=123https://domain2.com/example?p=123...";
>   urls.replace(/(https+:)/, '%%%$1').split('%%%');

The right answer is from @Teemu